# How to solve Projection Problem at client side

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system

I want to discuss a scenario here to all.

1. I have developed a Web mapping application in OpenLayers and GeoServer. The customer give us shapefiles with native projection SWREFF99_1330 (EPSG:3008).  i published this shapefile on Geoserver after changing its native projection from EPSG:3008 to EPSG:4326 by using ogr2ogr tool. The layer displayed perfectly over Google map layer in my OpenLayers Web Page.
2. Again, I publish this shapefile on GeoServer with its native projection (this time, without changing projection using ogr2ogr tool) and then i go to my page and figure out that the layer was not visible over Google map layer.

Now, my question to all members:

Is there any way to change the native projection from EPSG:3008 to EPSG:4326 at client side (in my OpenLayers web page code) ? so that the layer should display correctly over google base layer as in case 1.

Comment: The projection can also be done by GeoServer.

Answer (score 4):

You can project in Openlayers like this:

```
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3008"),
  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

[Proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/attachment/wiki/Download/proj4js-1.0.2.zip) is required to do this on the client side.

Comment: doesn't OL come bundled with proj4js?

Comment: This example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/web-mercator.html is using http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/web-mercator.js

Comment: OpenLayers integrates with Proj4js if the library is available > http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js